# Function of print() in a particular Python Tutorial example

Tags: python

The function `fib()` below taken from [chapter 4.6 in The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) includes at the end of the definition a line containing `print()` with no apparent reason since the same function without that line -`fib0()`- produces the same output. So what is the reason of including that in the function definition? Which function between fib() and fib0() is more efficient?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function

def fib(n):
        """print a fibonacci series up to n"""
        a, b = 0, 1
        while a < n:
            print(a, end=', ')
            a, b = b, a+b
        print()

def fib0(n):
        """print a fibonacci series up to n"""
        a, b = 0, 1
        while a < n:
            print(a, end=', ')
            a, b = b, a+b

fib(2000)
fib0(2000)
```

Output:

> 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597,
>   0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in `print()`. Fib has this, and the print function automatically puts a newline at the end. So fib will output an extra newline while fib0 won't. For example:

```
from __future__ import print_function

def fib(n):
        """print a fibonacci series up to n"""
        a, b = 0, 1
        while a < n:
            print(a, end=', ')
            a, b = b, a+b
        print()

def fib0(n):
        """print a fibonacci series up to n"""
        a, b = 0, 1
        while a < n:
            print(a, end=', ')
            a, b = b, a+b

fib0(2000)
fib(2000)
```

Output:

```
0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597,
```

Does not have the newline and prints one continuous list.

Comment: it was a perfect way to show me the reason, thanks. I will delete the questions since it´s costing me some of my few reputation points.

Comment: Not anymore... :)

Answer (score 1):

The unvarnished `print()` call at the end of the first implementation ensures that a newline is output. `print(a, end=', ')` follows its output of `a` with a comma and a space - the default value for `end` is `\n`.

If you were to alter your calling code to read

```
fib(2000)
print('|done|')
fib0(2000)
print('|done|')
```

you would observe the difference more easily.